# After recent update my netbook launcher in Ubuntu 10.04 has vanished

Tags: 10.04, launcher, ubuntu-netbook

After a recent system update my netbook launcher is not working and has vanished. I am able to see the title bar like system clock and other apps but not able to access any apps. I tried booting to the 2d edition and it works fine.. Can you help..

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to re-install Ubuntu Netbook's launcher.
Run the following in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-netbook`

That should do the trick for you.

Answer (score -1):

Try purging Unity's and Compiz's configuration files by reinstalling.

Open a terminal and write:

```
sudo apt-get purge unity compiz
sudo apt-get install unity compiz
```

This is a dirty solution though and you'll lose all custom configurations made to those two.

Comment: -1, he's using 10.04 Netbook Remix - Unity was added in 10.10 NBR.